# reactjs new class is this correct way to implement it?

Tags: reactjs

I have a main application (board game)
which opens a lobby class (which shows available games)
and from there you can open a game-table

to open a new table I do the following:

```
var newTable = new GameTable(operationId, tableId, instanceId);
var {gametables} = this.state;
gametables.push(newTable);
this.setState({gametables});
```

how can I give those arguments to this newly created class (have the idea its not working; also not complaining!!!!)

then for render I do this:

```
render() {
    const clientLoginState = this.state.clientLoginState;
    return (
        <div style={styleApp()} onContextMenu={this.onContextMenu} >
        {clientLoginState === 2 ? 
        (
            <div>
            <Lobby requestOpenTable={this.requestOpenTable}>
            </Lobby>
            {this.state.gametables.map((item, index) => (
               <div className='table' key={index} ><GameTable sendTableMessage={this.sendTableMessage.bind(this)}/></div>
            ))}             
            </div>              
        )
        :
        (
            <Login loginState={clientLoginState} sendLogin={this.sendLogin} />
        )
        }   
        </div>
    );
    const tables = this.state.gametables.map((table, i) => {
        return ({table});
    });                 
}
```

but here i supply "GameTable" this cannot be the class that I created, but it doesn't work when I supply "item". No game-table appears.

javascript used to be so easy :(

Answer (score 0):

```
const tables = this.state.gametables.map((table, i) => {
        return ({table});
    });
```

render method contains the JSX code. Try moving the above code to a helper function and call it from the render method.

Also your logic should be in helper functions not inside JSX.

place a helper function inside your class component

```
renderTable(){
const tables = this.state.gametables.map((table, i) => {
        return ({table});
    });    
}
```

then inside your jsx call

```
{this.renderTable}
```

Complete code:

```
renderTable(){
    const tables = this.state.gametables.map((table, i) => {
            return ({table});
        });    
    }

renderView(){
    const clientLoginState = this.state.clientLoginState;
        return (
            {clientLoginState === 2 ? 
            (
                <div>
                <Lobby requestOpenTable={this.requestOpenTable}>
                </Lobby>
                {this.state.gametables.map((item, index) => (
                   <div className='table' key={index} ><GameTable sendTableMessage={this.sendTableMessage.bind(this)}/></div>
                ))}             
                </div>              
            )
            :
            (
                <Login loginState={clientLoginState} sendLogin={this.sendLogin} />
            )
            }   
        );
    }

render() {
return (
 <div style={styleApp()} onContextMenu={this.onContextMenu} >
{this.renderView}
</div>
<div>{this.renderTable}</div>
)
}
```